# Is this large-leaved perennial a weed?

Tags: identification, weeds, perennials

Trying to decide if I should pull this. Anyone know what it is?

[image]
[image]

Comment: With [tag:identification] questions, it's useful to describe where in the world you found the plant, and the conditions where you found it (sun, shade, rocky hillside, forested riverbank, and so on). If you have more information about the plant, please update your question to add it. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I'm in westchester county NY in the U.S. This is in my garden, and might be something a previous owner of the house planted on purpose. Or might be a volunteer. We get loads of deer, which seem uninterested in it.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: What happened when the plant bloomed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would assume that this is a member of the [Aster](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aster_(genus)) family,  probably a Heliantheae (Sunflower relative), either [Heliopsis, aka Oxeye](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heliopsis) or [Echinacea](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Echinacea).

This would mean that most likely it was planted and is just about to develop buds which should start opening by July. Then you should see yellow (-> Oxeye) or purple flowers (-> Echinacea), making identification easier.